# Splitting a rectangular image to polygons to simulate Breaking glass

Tags: c#, algorithm, image, graphics, polygons

I am working on some C# code in which I would like to take a 2D rectangle and split it to smaller 2D polygons.  I would like the effect to look like the rectangle was made of glass and it was hit with a hammer in a random spot.  I was wondering if anyone knows of a good algorithm to help me with this.  I have tried the FortuneVoronoi code using random points to simulate this effect but am having a hard time turning the finished VoronoiGraph in to a set of non intersecting polygons in a reasonable amount of CPU time.

Comment: Interestingly enough, apparently no one knows for sure precisely what mechanisms underly glass fracturing in the first place. http://www.physorg.com/news7864.html

Comment: Cool link to the glass fracture understanding, thanks for that! It does not have to be exact, just a believable simulation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention Voronoi diagrams, I'd go for a Centroidal Voronoi diagram built using a radial density function that is concretated on the point of impact plus some jittering to add a bit of realism. See this [page](http://www.raskob.de/fun/d/index-en.php) and this [paper](http://www.math.psu.edu/qdu/Res/Pre/dfg99sirv.pdf).

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I will see if I can implement this in a reasonably efficient way.  I will be posting all this work publicly once it is complete, it is currently in the form of a simple C# screen saver for testing.  Just a fun project I have started is all.

Comment: @Jeff, try this library, but it's C++,. not C#. http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/cvt/cvt.html